# Embedding Python 3.3 in C++ from zipped standard library on Windows XP

Tags: python, c++, windows, python-3.x, windows-xp

I want to embed Python 3.3.4 in my C++ application so that:

- Python's standard library is always taken from a zip archive alongside my app's executable (shouldn't depend on any environment vars etc);
- my own custom .py modules are imported from *another* folder *or* zip archive alongside the executable.

And, in fact, I've almost managed to do it right. The only thing that still does not work is importing the standard library from a ZIP archive: it works ok as a simple directory, but whenever I try to zip it, initialization fails with the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
```

Is it even possible with latest Python? I've googled a lot for it and lots of sources claim that putting correct "python33.zip" near the executable should work. Still, my experiments prove otherwise. What am I missing?

Here's my test code - a minimal console application made by MS Visual Studio 2010, running on Windows XP SP3, with some comments as to what I tried and what are the results:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "python.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // calling or not calling Py_SetProgramName doesn't seem to change anything
    //Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);

    // python_lib is a directory with contents of python33/Lib
    // python_lib.zip is an equivalent ZIP archive with contents of python33/Lib (without any top-level subdirs)
    // _scripts.dat is a ZIP archive containing a custom script (hello.py)

    //Py_SetPath(L"python_lib;_scripts.dat"); // works fine! (non-zipped standard library, zipped custom script)

    Py_SetPath(L"python_lib.zip;_scripts.dat"); // both std library and scripts are zipped - fails with error "unable to load the file system codec" during Py_Initialize()

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                        "print('Today is',ctime(time()))\n");

    PyRun_SimpleString("import hello"); // runs hello.py from inside _scripts.dat (works fine if Py_Initialize succeeds)

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything including copying python33.zip to Windows\system32 (for some reason, "Windows\system32\python33.zip" is actually included in default Py_GetPath()). I also tried using Py_SetPythonHome. The results are always the same: working fine as long as standard library is not zipped, crashing as soon as it is.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of the path (as I already said, I tried specifying it in absolute form too), it just refuses to load standard library from a zip, but works with any "normal" directory. That's the main (and only) problem I see right now.

Comment: Also, I've just asked a person to try and run it on Win7. Same result (crash). So it doesn't seem to be specific to WinXP either.

Comment: Well, I've just re-created `python33.zip` with your 7z command line and result is still the same (tried to use absolute path too: `Py_SetPath(L"c:\\python33.zip");`). And yes, it also prints `ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`. Sorry I missed this earlier. Are you using the "stock" python .lib/.dll included in the package, or perhaps building them from sources?

Comment: Well then, I'm starting to think that something's wrong with either my PC or my head. :) Could you please email me (kirinyale[at]gmail.com) or otherwise share your executable and source so that I check if it runs on my side?

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a problem with Python 3.3.4 after all. I've installed 3.3.2 to another PC to test it there and it worked. Then I uninstalled 3.3.4 and replaced it with 3.3.2 on my main PC and it worked too. After reinstalling 3.3.4 again it doesn't work again. So much for using the latest version... :) Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was recently discovered and documented in [Python Issue 20621](http://bugs.python.org/issue20621).  A fix for it will be released in Python 3.3.5; 3.3.5 release candidate 2 is now available for testing.  http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.5/

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be some problem with Python 3.3.4. Installing 3.3.2 or 3.3.3 instead fixes everything instantly.

Filed this issue on Python's bug tracker:

http://bugs.python.org/issue20852